# Laravel AJAX call returns a date of 1 day before

Tags: database, laravel

On my Laravel app, I have created an AJAX call to search bookings based on a given name. In the database, every booking contains a date field. For some reason, the date I receive from my controller query is always the day before. So for example, when the date field in the database shows '2021-05-18', the collected date from the query shows '2021-05-17'.
Does anyone have an idea what can be the cause of this and how I can solve it?

I use the same date field in other controller functions and on other views as well, and there the date field is displaying correctly.

Also, in my config > app file I have set the 'timezone' to 'Europe/Brussels'.

A screenshot of my database:

[image]

The code in my controller is as follows:

```
public function searchReservation(Request $request)
{
    $users = User::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->name.'%')
    ->select('id', 'name')
    ->get();

    foreach($users as $user) {
        $user['reservations'] = Booking::where('user_id', $user['id'])->get();
    }

    return $users;
}
```

My code in the controller, where I 'transform' the date, before I create a new booking:

```
if (Carbon::hasFormat($request->date, 'd-m-Y')) {
        $request->date = Carbon::createFromFormat("d-m-Y", $request->date);
    } else {
        $request->date = Carbon::createFromFormat("d-n-Y", $request->date);
    }
```

A screenshot of my database output, where the date is always a day before the real date:

[image: View output]

Comment: Have you changed the timezone in your config file at a later time? In that case you should run php artisan config:clear to clear the config cache.

Comment: @zihad Indeed I have changed the timezone at a later time. But still, now that I have run the config clear command, the issue is still there.

Comment: What's your development stack? You may also check the server time and see if It's  adjusted to your time zone.

Comment: My development stack is the LAMP stack. How do I check my server time? Do I check this in the terminal, or by a query in Sequel Pro?

Comment: Yes, you may check your server time from the terminal. However, what is your procedure to save the data in the database. Can you confirm that data gets saved correctly with the correct time? The issue may also arise from the database storing the data with a different timezone. Though you can configure your timezone from config/app.php in Laravel, it's recommended to save all time related data in UTC and change the timezone on application level before serving it to the user. It will save you from a lot of hassle in the long run .

Comment: My timezone in the terminal is 'Europe/Brussels'. Before I store the date into the database, I transform it with Carbon, because the date notation is different when it comes from a form in Chrome, Safari or Firefox. Here is my code to do this:
if (Carbon::hasFormat($request->date, 'd-m-Y')) {
            $request->date = Carbon::createFromFormat("d-m-Y", $request->date);
        } else {
            $request->date = Carbon::createFromFormat("d-n-Y", $request->date);
        }

Comment: I have made an answer based on your comment. See if it resolves your issue.

Comment: Done so, implemented the code you suggested, but still with the same result.

Comment: That's weird. Can you update your question with sample input, related db record and finally the output that you are getting afterwards?

Comment: @zihad done so accordingly

Answer (score 0):

When you are using Carbon for formatting a time, you need to explicitly set the time zone if you intend to process with a time zone other than UTC. Default values like created_at will be automatically saved properly by Laravel respecting the timezone set in config/app.php. For other date/time column you need to explicitly set the timezone for formatting with Carbon. Therefore, your code should be like:

```
if (Carbon::hasFormat($request->date, 'd-m-Y')) 
{ $request->date = Carbon::createFromFormat("d-m-Y", $request->date, config('app.timezone')); //pass timezone value from config as the third parameter
} 
else { 
$request->date = Carbon::createFromFormat("d-n-Y", $request->date,config('app.timezone')); 
}
```